# Understanding semaphores with pthreads (code included)

Tags: locking, pthreads, mutex, semaphore

So in class, we learned about semaphores and stuff and our professor let us know that this code below would be handy to learn for our exam. Unfortunately our exam is on Friday, and *whole list of excuses*, i just need to be able to understand this code for the exam and for future cases. I understand that the mutex_t is a lock system and the cond_t is a condition system in which signals get passed through sema_P and sema_V (if the value is 0, race condition occurs and the thread is locked out by cond_wait until another thread increases the value and is unlocked by cond_signal), but why does a lock need to get passed around? Why is there a mutex_lock and mutex_unlock in both decrementer P() and incrementer V()? How does this work with the threads and the conditions (cont_t)?

```
typedef struct
{
        pthread_mutex_t lock;
        pthread_cond_t wait;
        int value;
} sema;

void pthread_sema_init(sema *s, int count)
{
        s->value = count;
        pthread_cond_init(&(s->wait),NULL);
        pthread_mutex_init(&(s->lock),NULL);
        return;
}

void pthread_sema_P(sema *s)
{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(s->lock));
        s->value--;
        if(s->value < 0) {
                pthread_cond_wait(&(s->wait),&(s->lock));
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(s->lock));
        return;
}

void pthread_sema_V(sema *s)
{

        pthread_mutex_lock(&(s->lock));
        s->value++;
        if(s->value <= 0) {
                pthread_cond_signal(&(s->wait));
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(s->lock));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutex `sema.lock` is there to protect the shared variable `sema.value`, ensuring that only one thread accesses that value at a time.  Both `pthread_sema_P()` and `pthread_sema_V()` must take the lock because they both access `sema.value`.

That implementation of sempahores is buggy, by the way - it doesn't handle spurious wakeups (a "spurious wakeup" is where `pthread_cond_wait()` wakes up despite not being signalled - this is allowed by the spec).

A more traditional implementation might be:

```
void pthread_sema_P(sema *s)
{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&s->lock);
        while (s->value < 1) {
                pthread_cond_wait(&s->wait, &s->lock);
        }
        s->value--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&s->lock);
}

void pthread_sema_V(sema *s)
{
        pthread_mutex_lock(&s->lock);
        s->value++;
        pthread_cond_signal(&s->wait);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&s->lock);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So how does the thread process goes. A thread runs, decrements the value and gets locked out due pthread_cond_wait(&(s->wait),&(s->lock)). The 2nd thread then picks up the lock and tries to increment the value , once it's incremented it signals the other thread to open up?

Comment: Yes.  But the other thread only returns from `pthread_cond_wait()` after it has re-acquired the mutex, which can only happen after the signalling thread has unlocked it.